# How do you set default value in mat-select within an *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to set a default value in mat-select within an *ngFor, however, accessing the element in the array from the loop is not working as wanted. Is there any similar way to this approach?

.ts file:

```
persons: Person[] = .. //consist of Person with name and age
```

.html file:

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons">
    {{ person.name }}
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(value)]="person.age">
         <mat-option value="10-20">10-20</mat-option>
         <mat-option value="20-30">20-30</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To set a default value, you need to populate your array with a value assigned to each object's `age` property. Then `mat-select` `[(value)]` binding can set the matching value as default.

Example ([Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-kruupz?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts)):

```
export class AppComponent {
  persons = [
    {
      name: 'John Smith',
      age: '30-40'
    },
    {
      name: 'Patrick Stewart',
      age: '10-20'
    }
    ,
    {
      name: 'Peter Parker',
      age: '20-30'
    }
  ]
}
```

If your array is dynamic, you can run a loop to assign a default value to each element as well.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.persons.forEach(item => item.age = '10-20'); // set the default age you want

}
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons">
  {{ person.name }}
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(value)]="person.age">
      <mat-option value="10-20">10-20</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="20-30">20-30</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="30-40">30-40</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]